# Raising a negative number to a fractional power, why the result is different?

Tags: functions, numerical-value

In the math theory, we know have
$$(x)^{\frac{m}{n}=}\sqrt[n]{x^m} \ ,$$
it means
$$(-1.5)^{\frac{1}{0.3}}=(-1.5)^{\frac{10}{3}}=\sqrt[3]{(-1.5)^{10}}=\sqrt[3]{1.5^{10}}\simeq 3.8634 \ .$$
But in mathematica, when we input

`(-1.5)^(1/0.3)`

we will get a complex number, i.e. 

`-1.93170528-3.3458117i`

Why the result is different? Which is right?

Comment: Both. In fact, it's a matter of choice which of the three complex cubic roots to return as a result. You chose the real one, Mathematica chose differently. Take a look at the result of `Solve[(-1.5)^(10) == x^3, x]`.

Comment: Look up the concept of "principal value" and the *Mathematica* function `Surd[]`.